# Confirm selected mail item is in a specific folder

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to build in a small check that confirms my currently selected mail item is in a certain folder (Inbox in this case), before following through with the rest of my code to save the email.

Something along the lines of:

```
If Not Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection = .Folder(olFolderInbox)
MsgBox Currently selected email is not in the inbox! Item skipped.", 1, "Mail Item Selection Error"
Else
End If
```

Or modifying my current code to:

```
For Each oMail In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection And Inside .Folder(olFolderInbox)
//Rest of code here
```

I assume it's a simple enough check but I can't seem to find the right VBA syntax to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I may have answered my own question, but I'll leave this here in case anybody happens to be following in my footsteps one day.

```
Dim objFolder As Folder
Set objFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)


If Not ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = objFolder Then
    MsgBox "Currently selected email is not in the inbox! Item not saved.", 1, "Mail Item Selection Error"
    Exit Sub
    Else
 End If
```

Comment: Be careful with `GetDefaultFolder`. When I first used Outlook, the default installation had a single store (file with extension of PST or OST) into which all emails were loaded. Now the default installation has one store per account plus one extra. The account stores will be listed in the Folder Pane as something like "johndoe@gmail.com". The extra store will be listed as "outlook data file".  Each store will have its own Inbox. Your emails are loaded to the Inbox within the appropriate account store but the default Inbox (as reported by `GetDefaultFolder`) will be in "outlook data file".

Answer (score 0):

Do not compare pointers - it will not work. Compare the entry ids using Namespace.CompareEntryIDs

```
If Not ns.CompareEntryIDs(ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.EntryID, objFolder.EntryID) Then
  ...
```